# reading String with spaces java

Tags: java

I am trying to read from scanner with spaces, i want to read even the spaces.
for example "john smith" to be read "john smith".

my code is as follow: 
when it gets to the space after john it just hangs and doesn't read any more.
any help would be appreciated.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

String userName = "";
while (in.hasNext()) {
    userName.concat(in.next());
}
```

Comment: why you do not use `scanner.nextLine();` i mean `in.nextLine();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scanner.next()` returns the next token, delimited by whitespace. If you would like to read the entire line, along with the spaces, use `nextLine()` instead:

```
String userName = in.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);  
scan.useDelimiter("\\Z");  
String content = scan.next();
```

or

```
 private String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws IOException {
            StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader(filePath));
            char[] buf = new char[1024];
            int numRead=0;
            while((numRead=reader.read(buf)) != -1){
                String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
                fileData.append(readData);
            }
            reader.close();
            return fileData.toString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When we use Scanner.next() to read token there is what we call a delimiter, the default delimiter used in by Scanner is \p{javaWhitespace}+ , you can get it by calling [Scanner.delimiter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#delimiter%28%29), which is any char that validate the [Character.isWhitespace(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29). you can use a customized delimiter for your Scanner using [Scanner.useDelimiter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29).

If you want to take one line as a string so you can use `nextLine()` , if you already know what is the type of the next token in the input stream, scanner gives you a list of method `next*()` take convert the token to the specified type. see Scanner's doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for more info.